# Can't find sshd process

Tags: ssh

Using PuTTY on my Windows laptop, I am able to `ssh` into my Mac desktop, but once I've logged in, I can't find any `sshd` process running on the Mac.  E.g. running the following right after ssh-ing into the Mac:

```
% ps -eo pid,command | grep sshd | grep -v grep
```

...produces no output.  *Of course, needless to say, I get the same results (no output) if I use `ps -ef` instead of `ps -eo pid,command`.*

Also, there's no `/var/run/sshd.pid` file.

What's going on?  Does OS X use a different program to handle incoming ssh logins?

Answer (score 10):

No - OS X uses [OpenSSH](http://www.opensource.apple.com/) and you can inspect the [source code used here](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/OpenSSH/OpenSSH-166.1/).

Based on your output, it looks like sshd is not active on the machine. Also `ps|grep ssh[d]` will prevent your grep process from matching the target. Some people get concerned when they don't see sshd running, since it gets started on demand when launchd detects an incoming network request. Are you certain ssh is active? You could verify this with `lsof|grep ssh` if you have doubts.

Look for this when one ssh has been initiated recently on Lion:

```
Last login: Mon Jul 16 17:58:26 2012 from 10.0.1.35
mac:~ mike$ ps -ef|grep sshd
0   60320     1   0  4:23PM ??         0:00.00 /usr/libexec/launchproxy /usr/sbin/sshd -i
0   60321 60320   0  4:23PM ??         0:00.15 /usr/sbin/sshd -i
501 60330 60321   0  4:23PM ??         0:00.01 /usr/sbin/sshd -i
501 60336 60331   0  4:23PM ttys003    0:00.00 grep sshd
```

Comment: Downvoted for not showing *also* the output you get from `ps -eo pid,command|grep sshd`.  It will show at least as many processes as those shown by `ps -ef|grep sshd`, proving that my failure to observe a `sshd` process is not explained by my choice of flags to `ps`.

Comment: Seriously - you down vote over a ps argument choice? The PID is clearly the second column and the command is the last column in the `-ef` but it's your vote to cast. Your criticism of everyone that stepped up to try to help seems an odd way to attract more help.

Comment: My comment, and downvote, was in response to your original post, which started: "It looks like your syntax is a bit off."  *Which syntax* in particular is off, and how exactly does this "off syntax" cause my not being able to see an `sshd` process?  Later you write: "Also `ps|grep ssh[d]` will prevent your grep process from matching the target."  I don't see why this is relevant, since, I did *not* use `ps|grep sshd`, nor did I use `ps|grep ssh`.  Finally,...

Comment: ...you wrote: "Some people get concerned when they don't see sshd running, since it gets started on demand when launchd detects an incoming network request."  Given that I clearly wrote that I searched for the `sshd` process immediately *after* `ssh`-ing into the Mac, your last remark, as well as the questions you ask in the revised version of your answer, make me question whether you actually read my post.

Answer (score 4):

Is it okay to post to a really old question... I was looking to answer the same today and will attempt to clarify the clarify.

Remote Login enabled in System Preferences Sharing and port 22 is open:

```
% netstat -p tcp -lna | grep '\*\.22'
tcp4       0      0  *.22 *.*  LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0  *.22 *.*  LISTEN
```

Then lsof shows launchd is the one listening (found the right options for lsof in the man page and executed as root):

```
# lsof -iTCP -sTCP:LISTEN | grep ssh
launchd    1 root   50u  IPv6 0xc3c700cb936cd50f      0t0  TCP *:ssh (LISTEN)
launchd    1 root   51u  IPv4 0xc3c700cb9452be6f      0t0  TCP *:ssh (LISTEN)
launchd    1 root   53u  IPv6 0xc3c700cb936cd50f      0t0  TCP *:ssh (LISTEN)
launchd    1 root   58u  IPv4 0xc3c700cb9452be6f      0t0  TCP *:ssh (LISTEN)
```

And when you ssh into the system you see that ssh-agent and sshd are spawned to deal with the connection.

```
 # ps -ef | grep ssh | grep -v grep
 501  1231     1   0 12:52PM ??         0:00.02 /usr/bin/ssh-agent -l
 0    1257     1   0 12:53PM ??         0:00.04 sshd: xxxxx [priv] 
 501  1259  1257   0 12:53PM ??         0:00.02 sshd: xxxxx@ttys002
```

Comment: Are you implying that `ssh-agent` runs on the remote side, and that it is responsible to deal with the connection? How does this fit to `man ssh-agent` stating that `ssh-agent` is »started in the beginning of […] a login session« and then »used for authentication when logging in to other machines using ssh«? Doesn’t this imply that the agent rather runs on the local side rather than the remote side, typically before the user has even started ssh to connect to a remote server?